# dataTables button collection: programmatically enable/disable nested buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using a jQuery DataTable. On the top, there are many buttons that will eventually call different actions for the selected rows.
Two of these buttons actually hold a collection of buttons.
The buttons should only be enabled under certain conditions, depending on which rows are selected.
The main buttons are very easy to enable/disable as found in the examples https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/api/enable.html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    select: true,
    buttons: [{
      text: 'Action1',
      enabled: false
    }, {
      text: 'More actions',
      enabled: false,
      extend: 'collection',
      buttons: [{
        text: 'Sub-action1',
        enable: false
      }, {
        text: 'Sub-action2',
        enable: false
      }]
    }, {
      text: 'Action2'
      enable: true
    }]
  });
});
```

To enable Action1 or Action2, I simply use their indexed position:

```js
table.button(0).enable(condition); // Changes Action1
table.button(2).enable(condition); // Changes Action2
```

But I also need to enable/disable buttons within a collection. In this example: Sub-Action1 and Sub-Action2.
How do I access those?

Comment: what if you used 1.1? Or rather, 0.0, or 0.1

Comment: The syntax is actually '1-1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey refer to this link :- https://datatables.net/reference/type/button-selector

this may help !